# C++ - I read a whole file (_which is a list of words separated by 2 white spaces_), how do i get the words separately fast?

Tags: c++, performance, file, buffer, multimap

I have read a file with around 120k words so i try to do it fast.
have seen the:

```
int x = setvbuf(fp, (char *)NULL, _IOFBF, BSZ);
assert( x == 0 && fp != NULL );
```

option but it takes more than a second ( 1 mb file)
so now i tried this method :

```
fopen_s (&pFile,DICT,"rb");
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

// obtain file size:
fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell (pFile);
rewind (pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
```

how do i continue from here?
buffer holds a list of words and i want to get them one by one as fast as possible
because im building a multimap with those words.

thank you!

Comment: What are your constraints(i.e. how fast do you need this to be)?
What have you tried so far and how far beyond that performance level are the results?

Comment: Are there situations where you have two words separated by one space that you need to treat as one word?  Is that the reason for two spaces?  Is each word always preceded by two spaces or is each word always followed by two spaces?  Or is the two space word separator only between nonempty words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read all the words like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;  // that's the way I like it... :-)

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;   // all the words
    string word;
    ifstream f("myfile.txt");  // open stream for input

    while (f) {
        f >> word;          // read word
        if (!f) break;
        v.push_back(word);  // push word into vector
    }

    // now v holds all the words in the file, and you can iterate them

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're testing the stream state twice every loop iteration. It's simpler to just say `while (f >> word) { v.push_back(word); }`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is essentially implementing `mmap()`.
The beauty of `mmap()` is that it will load the actual pages in memory when needed. If your app reads them sequentially very fast, the OS will map the pages as fast as it can.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
    { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

int
main(void)
{
    int fd = open("english-words.10", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        handle_error("open");

    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)
        handle_error("fstat");
    size_t lSize = sb.st_size;

    char* buffer = mmap(NULL, lSize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (buffer == MAP_FAILED)
        handle_error("mmap");

    // insert your mapping to a map here

    munmap(buffer, lSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I also use `fstat()` instead of your `fseek`/`ftell`.

Answer (score 0):

Separating the words just isn't going to be the bottleneck. Any reasonable implementation will be faster than even an SSD.